# Keras model, training data format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have some data in a cvs. I made a preprocess, now they look like that:

> [array([66,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]), array([18,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]), array([26, 34,  9, 41, 19, 23, 29, 30,  1,  0]), array([15,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])]

for one line, it's an array of arrays

And I have a array of results 0 if it's false and 1 if it's true.

with keras and a lot of data I want in result a float between 0 and 1.

For now keras gave me an error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

So I was thinking that my data aren't in good format.
If I take only one column it's working...

Have I to concat all arrays in one for each row or I have the wrong keras model?

here my definition of keras model:

```
df = dataset.values.tolist()

X = df
y = dataset['result']

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit the keras model on the dataset
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
```

if I didn't convert list to numpy I get this error:

> Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays.

Comment: Hi, As the Error suggested , I tried with arrays of arrays like below ,It was able to train.            
X = [[66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
y = [[0],[1]]              ,                                                                                                                   Could you change your datasets like that ?

Comment: Hi, I made somethings like that X = [66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] y = 1, and I was able to train, at first I didn't understand that for training sub array in must have same number of sub array in y